# Using summary with tf slim or tf layers

Tags: tensorflow

I cannot not find how to add a summary to visualize weights for networks which have been defined with `tf.contrib.slim` or `tf.contrib.layers`.

For instance, if I have:

```
net = slim.conv2d(net, ...)
```

How can I add the weights and bias into a summary ?

Edit: I just saw that I could use `tf.contrib.layers.summarize_collection`. That probably works for what I want to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the solution I found after deeper investigation, in case someone has the same problem than me.

For `tf.contrib.slim`, (deprecated) the weights are added to the collection `tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` which can be visualized with:

```
tf.contrib.layers.summarize_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
```

For `tf.contrib.layers`, there are some convenience methods

```python
tf.contrib.layers.summarize_weights()  # tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS
tf.contrib.layers.summarize_biases()  # tf.GraphKeys.BIASES
# For tf >= 1.3:
tf.contrib.layers.summarize_tensors()
```

To have a better control on which variables add, it's possible by customizing the code of [summarize_collection](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/summaries.py).

Comment: `tf.contrib.layers.summarize_weights()  # tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS
tf.contrib.layers.summarize_biases()  # tf.GraphKeys.BIASES`
were removed from tensorflow modules. Can you please update the answer?

Comment: I guess the question can be updated with `tf.contrib.layers.summarize_tensors()`